# Cola de prioridad PriorityQueue Maximos en java

Tags: java

quisiera entender esto de porque es que esto me da un cola de prioridades de minimos si yo le asigno mayor prioridad al que tiene mayor valor

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>((n1,n2) -> {
     if(n1 > n2)
         return 1;
     else if(n1 < n2)
         return -1;
     else
         return 0;
 });
```

gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(n1.getPuntaje() < n2.getPuntaje()){ //si el objeto1(el que ya estaba en la cola) < objeto2 (nuevo) , el objeto2 tendra mayor prioridad que el objeto1 
            return 1;}
 else if(n1.getPuntaje() > n2.getPuntaje()) //si el objeto1(el que ya estaba en la cola) > objeto2 (nuevo) , el objeto1 tendra mayor prioridad que el objeto2
            return -1;`introducir el código aquí`
        else
            return 0;
```

Comment: Hola. Procura incluir siempre una breve explicación sobre por qué tu código responde a la pregunta. Este otro código usa n1 y n2 como instancias de una clase diferente a Integer...